# NodeJS concurrently/asynchronously generating views for performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express, ejs

I'm new to NodeJS, and I'm attracted to the performance benefits of asynchronously and concurrently performing IO operations so that the total request time is closer to the time required to perform the slowest IO operation rather than the sum of all IO operations.

However all the callbacks are a bit messy and I want to do my best to make my code as DRY as possible.

I have a simple 'brochure' type 5 page website that loads header + body + footer views for any normal page request, but loads only the body for an AJAX request (with a get param 'ajaxify') -- the resulting content is injected into the body of the page on the client.

I'm looking for some tips on how to manage my code design when dealing with concurrent/asynchronous IO operations and form a response when all IO operations have completed.

This is my first try with a NodeJS module (written in coffeescript -- I've supplied the compiled javascript as well)

Is there any type of design pattern for this type of problem that is commonly used?

```
os                    = require 'os'
url                   = require 'url'
html_minifier   = require 'html-minifier'

render_views = (req, res, body_view, code = 200) ->

  complete = (arg) ->

    response  = arg.response
    code      = arg.code

    if query.hasOwnProperty 'ajaxify'
      res.send html_minifier.minify response.body,
        collapseWhitespace: true
        removeComments: true,
        code
    else
      if response.header != '' and response.body != '' and response.footer != ''
        res.send html_minifier.minify response.header + response.body + response.footer,
          collapseWhitespace: true
          removeComments: true,
          code

  query = url.parse(req.url, true).query

  response = 
    header: ''
    body:   ''
    footer: ''

  if query.hasOwnProperty 'ajaxify'

    code = 200
    res.render body_view, {}, (err, html) ->
      response.body = html
      complete
        response: response
        code:     code

  else
    res.render body_view, {}, (err, html) ->
      response.body = html
      complete
        response: response
        code:     code

    res.render 'view_header', {}, (err, html) -> 
      response.header = html
      complete 
        response: response
        code:     code

    res.render 'view_footer', {}, (err, html) -> 
      response.footer = html
      complete 
        response: response
        code:     code


exports.index = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_index')

exports.services = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_services')

exports.about = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_about')

exports.blog = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_blog')

exports.contact = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_contact')

exports.error = (req, res) ->
  render_views(req, res, 'view_error', '404')
```

And regular compiled javascript:

```
    // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function() {
  var html_minifier, os, render_views, url;

  os = require('os');

  url = require('url');

  html_minifier = require('html-minifier');

  render_views = function(req, res, body_view, code) {
    var complete, query, response;
    if (code == null) {
      code = 200;
    }
    complete = function(arg) {
      var response;
      response = arg.response;
      code = arg.code;
      if (query.hasOwnProperty('ajaxify')) {
        return res.send(html_minifier.minify(response.body, {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true
        }, code));
      } else {
        if (response.header !== '' && response.body !== '' && response.footer !== '') {
          return res.send(html_minifier.minify(response.header + response.body + response.footer, {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
          }, code));
        }
      }
    };
    query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    response = {
      header: '',
      body: '',
      footer: ''
    };
    if (query.hasOwnProperty('ajaxify')) {
      code = 200;
      return res.render(body_view, {}, function(err, html) {
        response.body = html;
        return complete({
          response: response,
          code: code
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.render(body_view, {}, function(err, html) {
        response.body = html;
        return complete({
          response: response,
          code: code
        });
      });
      res.render('view_header', {}, function(err, html) {
        response.header = html;
        return complete({
          response: response,
          code: code
        });
      });
      return res.render('view_footer', {}, function(err, html) {
        response.footer = html;
        return complete({
          response: response,
          code: code
        });
      });
    }
  };

  exports.index = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_index');
  };

  exports.services = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_services');
  };

  exports.about = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_about');
  };

  exports.blog = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_blog');
  };

  exports.contact = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_contact');
  };

  exports.error = function(req, res) {
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_error', '404');
  };

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code a little bit (assuming you are using express) by using [req.xhr](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.xhr) (or by checking for the X-Requested-With header). This way you can drop all the query string stuff...

Replace

```
query.hasOwnProperty('ajaxify')
```

with

```
req.xhr
```

Alternatively you could move the logic straight to the view if you like... just put if(!req.xhr) equivalent around header/footer and it will all be done there. All your render_views method would do in that case is call res.render and do the html minification (Making it much simpler).